# Direct input to ncurses software after sending to background

Tags: bash, background-process, ncurses

I've a question for you experts.

I have a server that uses ncurses to show data sent via sockets by an MPI software. I'm trying to start the server in background, launch the MPI process, then resume the server.

I've written a small bash script:

```
echo "starting monitor"
./server &
jobnumber=$(jobs | grep './server &' | grep -o '\[[0-9]*\]' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)

mpiexec [...]

fg $jobnumber
```

Everything runs smoothly but for one thing: the server doesn't wait for a key push to die, and suddenly dies.
I think there is something wrong with the input redirection, but I really need you advice. Thanks in advance!

Have fun

gf

P.S.: the server can be reduced to:

```
int main(){
    initscr();
    [...]
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need `expect` to interact with the server.

Comment: Removing the ellipsis and including `curses.h`, the reduced program responds to `^Z` as expected.  More information is needed.

Comment: Curses has obviously been included, and the issue is not about keyboard shortcuts, but automatic behavior.
Thank to glenn for the suggestion.
I've solved the problem, solution in the following answer.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the typo fixing!

Answer (score 0):

To keep the input redirection to the foreground job you have to run the script in monitor mode.
Add:

```
    set -m
```

to the first line of the script. So you'll have:

```
#Set monitor mode
set -m

echo "starting monitor"
./server &
jobnumber=$(jobs | grep './server &' | grep -o '\[[0-9]*\]' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)

mpiexec [...]

fg $jobnumber
```

Now input redirection works like a charm.
Have fun

gf

Comment: According to bash's [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), `-m` is on by default.

Comment: So why is the evidence confirming that the script doesn't work without, but works with it specified?

Comment: Perhaps you are running the script in a non-interactive manner, e.g., from a launcher or cronjob (the question provides no detail).  Running it from the command-line should have the documented default for `-m`.

Comment: Maybe the send back - bring to front sequence just causes it to not to run in monitor mode.

Comment: If it were that simple, ncurses applications could not be suspended and resumed (this is a feature that has worked reliably for 20 years).